# unzipping backup of sdcard, wrong folder structure

Tags: adb, zip

I have a backup of my old phone in my computer, in a folder called `phone_backup`

it contains the usual folders:

- Airdroid
- Alarms
- Android
- Audiobooks
- AuthenticatorPlus
- Books
- DCIM
- Documents
- doubleTwist
- Download
- MEGA
- Movies
- Music
- Neobackup
- Notifications
- Pictures
- Podcasts

I have zipped the contents of `phone_backup` and transferred to the sdcard of my new phone.

If I open, in Windows, `phone_backup` or `phone_backup.zip` and check the Download folder I see the same I have on my old phone, however, when I do `unzip phone_backup.zip` everything seems to work until I get the error

`unzip: couldn't create file Download/Videos: Is a directory`

And if I do `find Download/ -maxdepth 1 -type d` I get:

- Download/
- Download/Videos
- Download/WhatsApp
- Download/Airdroid
- Download/Alarms
- Download/Android
- Download/PowerTube

For some reason it's decompressing the root inside the Downloads folder?

```
redwood:/sdcard $ ls -lah Videos/ Download/Videos/
Download/Videos:
total 3.0K
drwxrws--- 2 u0_a402 media_rw 3.3K 2023-12-01 21:50 work

Videos:
total 3.0K
drwxrws--- 2 u0_a402 media_rw 3.3K 2023-12-02 09:02 work
```

same content too.

Why could this happen??

Answer (score 0):

You can't transfer apps and data from one phone to another in this fashion.  Try using the Android Backup, or Samsung Tool (if you have a Samsung phone) or for another Backup app on App Store.

Even if you manage to transfer the files over, it is not going to work.

Comment: I does work, I've done it multiple times. (Not zip, just adb pull then adb push to the new phone)